# How to get HTTPS url using REQUEST in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, request, python-requests

I'm tring to get the https url https://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx using REQUESTS library of python. However it shows error while using get method.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.post('https://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx',verify=False)
```

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xlnindia.gov.in', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

However, when I tried using **verify = False**, it doesn't give error but just a warning. But, later on further processing unsecure web page, it gives error as **Response 500**. So I want to use the secure HTTPS.

> C:\pythonNJ\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:847:
>   InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding
>   certificate verification is strongly advised.

I even tried adding headers to the get method, but still it gives the same error.

```
url = 'https://xlnindia.gov.in/frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.90 Safari/537.36'} 
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}) 
response
```

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xlnindia.gov.in', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url: /frm_G_Cold_S_Query.aspx (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

Can someone please help me how to get the HTTPS url using REQUEST library.

Comment: http://steven.casagrande.io/articles/python-requests-and-ssl/ Read the part right under `But then you'll have to look at SSL disabled warnings every time you make a query, and who wants that?`

Comment: what's `dictinfo`?

Comment: @StamKaly - Thanks Stam, I'll try if it could lead the way.